# SQL to 1 hot vector

Tags: mysql, sql

Need Help On an SQL problem
I have a table like table1

```
id labels.1 labels.2 labels.3 labels.4 ....              table1
1      a            b             c      null 
2       b            d            a      null
```

I want my tuples to be 1-hot vector like

```
            table2
id      a      b      c      d ...
1       1      1      1      0 
2       1      1      0      1
```

My solution:
Covert table1 to table3, and with t3, I can use if x IN label to decide whether a column should be 1 or 0, but I was stuck at the converting, I think I should use unpivot, but I don't know how, any ideas, or any smarter solutions

```
    table3
id    label                          
1      a
1      b
1      c
2      a
2      b
2      d
```

Comment: Thank you Serg for editing my post

Comment: Share what you have tried so far